# How can I redirect method's output into a txt file in python

Tags: python, io, pyqt

I have created a GUI using PyQt and now I want to direct the input in QlineEdit into the text file. I have created get_values() method which prints the values from the text fields. How can I redirect those printed strings into the .txt file.

Here's the method:

```
 def get_values(self) :
    print self.lineEdit.text()
    print self.lineEdit_2.text()
    print self.lineEdit_3.text()
    self.radio_button_clicked()
    print self.lineEdit_5.text()
    print self.lineEdit_6.text()
```

Comment: Redirect without modifying the method, or change the method to write to a file?

Comment: Redirect the method without modifying.

Comment: Note that redirecting stdout is hackish (not the shell redirect, but in python). You should design your method/class to accept a sink for your text (some writer, for example `print()` function, if you'd use 3...).

Comment: `import sys`; `def get_values(self, file=sys.stdout): print >> file, self.lineEdit.text()`

Comment: (and while at it, yes, Python 3 would be nice ;)